# Can 'await' be used inside Future.delayed?

Tags: flutter

```
 Future.delayed(duration, () async {
      await aFunction();
    });
```

This is what i tried but it didn't work. I want to run an await function after a duration delay. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to await delayed future:

```dart
await Future.delayed(delay, () async => await aFunction());
```